# PHP + Wordpress + CF7 -> how to add custom HTML inside span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap AND IMMEDIATELY AFTER input.wpcf7-form-control?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, action, contact-form-7

Contact Fom 7 - how to add custom HTML inside span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap AND IMMEDIATELY AFTER input.wpcf7-form-control ?
Using the 'Query Monitor' plugin I found that the HOOK which I need to modify is inside the:

'/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/text.php' file, namely **'wpcf7_add_form_tag_text'** hook

My attepmt (I wrote this code inside functions.php insite my theme) is:

```
function test($html) {

$html = sprintf(
'<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s<span class="focus-input100-1"></span><span class="focus-input100-2"></span></span>',
sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error );
return $html;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_add_form_tag_text', 'test');
```

...but it does not work

Comment: can you please elaborate. what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want to add '<span class="focus-input100-1"></span>' immediately after <input class="wpcf7-form-control">

Answer (score 0):

try to add the line here in the form editor

[image: wordpress screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

`wpcf7_add_form_tag_text` is not a filter or a hook, but rather it's a function.  So what you're trying simply won't work.

I would recommend using jQuery to add your data after.

The typical output from a Contact Form 7 Form is like this, on the front end.

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
    <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="First Name:">
</span>
```

In your CF7 Form Editor.  Simply add something like this below.  It can be after your [submit] tag even.  This will add the `<span class="focus-input100-1"></span>` immediately after the `<input>` tag but still inside the `wpcf7-form-control-wrap` wrapper.  You can adjust the input name or add additional rows depending on your form tag names.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery('input[name="your-name"]').after('<span class="focus-input100-1"></span>');
</script>
```

The result of above looks like this:

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
   <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="First Name:">
   <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
</span>
```